# Having dashes change into guessed letters

Tags: java

my program currently takes a random word and turns into dashes based on how many letters are in the word. I then determine if a letter guessed is in the word, but I was unable to figure out how to have the correctly guessed letter replace the dashes accordingly. I looked through possible solutions on the site, but was unable to have one work for my current code.

Code:

```
public String hiddenWord(){
     word = randomWord.getRandomWord();
     String dashes = word.replaceAll("[^ ]", " _ ");
     return dashes;
}

public String guessNotification(){
    if(word.indexOf(hv.keyChar)!=-1 && (hv.keyChar >= 'a' && hv.keyChar <= 'z')) {
        letterGuessed = "There is a " + hv.keyChar + " in the word";
    }
    else if(word.indexOf(hv.keyChar)==-1 && (hv.keyChar >= 'a' && hv.keyChar <= 'z')) {
        letterGuessed = "No " + hv.keyChar + " in the word";
        guesses++;
        System.out.println(guesses);

    }
    else{
        letterGuessed = "Not a valid letter";
    }
    return letterGuessed;
}

public void newGame() {
    hv.createNotification(this, size);  
    guesses = 0;
    System.out.println(word);
}
}
```

Comment: You'll have to save the word guessed so far in a variable, say `guessedWord`.  You can't use `String` because Java `String`s are immutable (they cannot be changed).  You can use `StringBuffer` or a `char` array.  `word.indexOf(hv.keyChar)` gives you the index of the letter in the word that the user guessed.  Use that index to set the appropriate character in `guessedWord`.  For example, if you've defined `dashes` as a StringBuffer, you can use `guessedWord.setCharAt(word.indexOf(hv.keyChar),hv.keyChar)`.

Comment: If you want to replace every instance of the character that the user guessed correctly, you'll have to repeatedly call `word.indexOf` to get every index until it returns -1.

Comment: @DavidChoweller Im not sure if I am understanding you correctly, so I edited the code above to reflect the changes I made based on your suggestion. I am confused about what to do with the guessed letter.

Comment: There is a problem with your modification because if the letter the user guessed is wrong, indexOf  will return -1 and that will cause an exception when you use `setCharAt()` with a negative index.

Comment: Actually, I noticed now that you have two spaces around each dash character.  That changes the logic a little.  I will add an answer that might show you how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how the logic of how to replace the appropriate dash with the correct user guess might look

```
    public static String guessNotification(String word, char userGuess, StringBuilder dashes) {

        int guessedIndex = word.indexOf(userGuess);
        if (guessedIndex != -1 && (userGuess >= 'a' && userGuess <= 'z')) {

            letterGuessed = "There is a " + userGuess + " in the word";
            dashes.setCharAt(guessedIndex*3+1, userGuess);

        }

        else if (guessedIndex == -1 && (userGuess >= 'a' && userGuess <= 'z')) {

            letterGuessed = "No " + userGuess + " in the word";
            guesses++;

        }
        else {

            letterGuessed = "Not a valid letter";

        }

        return letterGuessed;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One last question, I am calling guess notification in a separate class, so how should I call it? What arguments ?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to implement `guessNotification` as I've shown (i.e., as a static method with three arguments).  You can keep it as a class method, just making sure that the `userGuess` and `dashes` `StringBuilder` are accessible from in your method (perhaps as instance variables).

Comment: got it!! Thank you for help. Oh I just noticed.. what do I do with the word that has spaces? such as hard disk

Comment: That complicates things a bit, because you treat spaces differently from other characters when constructing the word with dashes.  For all other characters, you surround them with a space on each side.  It might be better, instead of storing the dashes array, to compute it every time you need to display it.  So you'd store a partially guessed word or phrase, with all the characters guessed by the user filled in, and all the unguessed characters with dashes.  To display this partially guessed word, you'd just surround each character or dash (except for a space) with a space on each side.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are all correct. But you may want to see example code: Add an array of correct guesses:

```
char[] correct = new char[26];  // or more, depends on whether u use non ascii chars
```

Initialize the array with e.g. ' '. Then replace the dashes:

```
StringBuilder guessedPart = new StringBuilder;
for (int lc = 0; lc < word.lenght(); lc++) {
  for (char c : correct)
    if (word.indexOf(lc) = c) guessedPart.append(c);
  if (guessedPart.length() < lc) guessedPart.append('_');
String guessedWord = guessedPart.toString();
```

That should do.